# Java/mongodb - How to implement aggregate method to return result as cursor

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am facing below issue

```
com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:15847" , "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)" , "code" : 16389 , "ok" : 0.0}
```

After googling I found some work around like using below code

1. `{"$out":"temp_colls");`
2. `useCursor=True`

1st one is working for me but its taking too much time around 3-4 minutes.

So looking for second option I have tried with below

Original code is

```
dbObjArray = new BasicDBObject[2]
dbObjArray[0]= cruxLevel
dbObjArray[1] = project                                  
List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(dbObjArray)
       if (!datasetObject?.isFlat && jsonFor != 'collection-grid') {
    output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(pipeline)
       }else{
            output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(project)
       }
output.results().eachWithIndex{list,index->
dataList.add(output.results()[index])
```

I have tried below to get result in **cursor**.

1.

```
   // Assuming MongoCollection
   dataSetCollection.aggregate(pipeline).useCursor(true)
```

You might also need to tell it to use disk space on the server rather than doing it all in memory:

2.

```
  // Assuming MongoCollection
  dataSetCollection.aggregate(pipeline).useCursor(true).allowDiskUse(true)
```

If you're using an older driver (or the old API in the new driver) those two options would look like this:

3.

```
   // Assuming DBCollection
    dataSetCollection.aggregate(pipeline, AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(true)
    .useCursor(true)
    .build())
   .useCursor(true)
```

And

```
 output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(project).newAggregationOptions().outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR).build()
```

Giving error for example

For  *"output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(project).useCursor(true)"*

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.AggregationOutput.useCursor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
```

For *"output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(project).useCursor(true).allowDiskUse(true)"*

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.AggregationOutput.useCursor() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]
```

For *"output= dataSetCollection.aggregate(project,AggregationOptions.builder()
    .allowDiskUse(true)
        .useCursor(true)
        .build())
    .useCursor(true)"*

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AggregationOptions for class: com.acumetric.hrat.aggregator.DataImportService
```

And for last one respectively.

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.AggregationOutput.newAggregationOptions() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Nothing is working. Where I am going wrong please help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **else** block put below code

```
def dbObjArray = new BasicDBObject[1]
dbObjArray[0]= project
List<DBObject> flatPipeline = Arrays.asList(dbObjArray)
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = AggregationOptions.builder()
                                    .batchSize(100)
                                    .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.CURSOR)
                                    .allowDiskUse(true)
                                    .build();
def cursor = dataSetCollection.aggregate(flatPipeline,aggregationOptions)
```

Comment: @user4408375 I'm unable to find method batchSize() under AggregationOptions. Im using driver version 3.0.4